# SOS I am crazy but haven't found the reason why the line 137 doesn't work

Tags: c, csv

The code is intended to read the each line from a CSV file (which is separated by comma), and then insert each line as a value into a binary tree.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_CHAR 128
#define MAX_LINE 512
#define COMMA ","

typedef struct node node_t;
typedef struct {
    node_t *root;
    int (*cmp)(void *, void *);
} tree_t;

typedef struct {
    char id[MAX_CHAR];
    char sex[MAX_CHAR];
    char age[MAX_CHAR];
    char height[MAX_CHAR];
    char weight[MAX_CHAR];
    char team[MAX_CHAR];
    char noc[MAX_CHAR];
    char games[MAX_CHAR];
    char year[MAX_CHAR];
    char season[MAX_CHAR];
    char city[MAX_CHAR];
    char sport[MAX_CHAR];
    char event[MAX_CHAR];
    char medal[MAX_CHAR];
} data_t;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    data_t data;
} athlete_t;

struct node {
    athlete_t *data;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
};

tree_t *make_empty_tree(int func(void *, void *));
void insert_to_struct(athlete_t *, char *);
tree_t *read_file(char*, tree_t *);
int cmp(void *p1, void *p2);
tree_t *insert_in_order(tree_t *, athlete_t *);
node_t *recursive_insert(node_t *, node_t *, int cmp(void *, void *));
void traverse_tree(tree_t *, void action(void *));
void recursive_traverse(node_t *, void action(void *));
void action(void *);
void ini_struct(athlete_t *);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    tree_t *tree = make_empty_tree(cmp);
    tree = read_file(argv[1], tree);
    printf("%s\n", tree->root->data->name);
    traverse_tree(tree, action);
    return 0;
}

/* Read each line from a file, and assume max length of line is 512 chars*/
tree_t *read_file(char *filename, tree_t *tree) {
    FILE *fp_data;
    char new_line[MAX_LINE];
    athlete_t *data_struct;

    fp_data = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fp_data == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(new_line, MAX_LINE, fp_data) != NULL) {
        data_struct = (athlete_t *)malloc(sizeof(*data_struct));
        ini_struct(data_struct);
        insert_to_struct(data_struct, new_line);
        tree = insert_in_order(tree, data_struct);
        printf("%s\n", new_line);
    }
    printf("%s \n", new_line);
    fclose(fp_data);
    return tree;
}

/* initialize the struct */
void ini_struct(athlete_t *data_struct) {
    strcpy(data_struct->data.id, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->name, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.sex, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.age, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.height, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.weight, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.team, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.noc, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.games, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.year, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.season, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.city, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.sport, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.event, "");
    strcpy(data_struct->data.medal, "");
}

/* make a empty tree */
tree_t *make_empty_tree(int func(void *, void *)) {
    tree_t *tree;
    tree = (tree_t *)malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    assert(tree != NULL);
    tree->root = NULL;
    tree->cmp = func;
    return tree;
}

/* insert each value separated by comma into the struct we define */
void insert_to_struct(athlete_t *data_struct, char *new_line) {
    sscanf(new_line, \
           "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]", \
           data_struct->data.id, data_struct->name, data_struct->data.sex, \
           data_struct->data.age, data_struct->data.height,\
           data_struct->data.weight,data_struct->data.team, \
           data_struct->data.noc, data_struct->data.games, \
           data_struct->data.year, data_struct->data.season, \
           data_struct->data.city, data_struct->data.sport, \
           data_struct->data.event, data_struct->data.medal);
}

int cmp(void *p1, void *p2) {
    char *s1 = (char *)p1;
    char *s2 = (char *)p2;

    return strcmp(s1, s2);
}

/* insert the struct into the tree */
tree_t *insert_in_order(tree_t *tree, athlete_t *value) {
    node_t *new;
    new = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    assert(new != NULL);
    new->data = value;
    new->left = new->right = NULL;
    tree->root = recursive_insert(tree->root, new, tree->cmp);
    return tree;
}

node_t *recursive_insert(node_t *root, node_t *new, int cmp(void*, void*)) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        return new;
    } else if (cmp(new->data->name, root->data->name) <= 0) {
        root->left = recursive_insert(root->left, new, cmp);
    } else {
        root->right = recursive_insert(root->right, new, cmp);
    }
    return root;
}

void recursive_traverse(node_t *root, void action(void *)) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        recursive_traverse(root->left, action);
        action(root->data->name);
        recursive_traverse(root->right, action);
    }
}

void traverse_tree(tree_t *tree, void action(void *)) {
    assert(tree != NULL);
    recursive_traverse(tree->root, action);
}

void action(void *p1) {
    printf("%s\n", (char*)p1);
}
```

The tricky thing happened in the `make_empty_tree` function, when I use `malloc` to create a pointer called new, but it doesn't work when I am debugging, but I think it should work!

Comment: Hi, I've edited your post for clarity. Please format your code next time and keep the question separate, not as comment in the code. Refrain from including the same pointless comment over and over, that's just distracting. Please take the [tour] of the site to understand how to ask good questions that will get good answers. Then come back and [edit] your question; best would be a [mcve]. "does not work" is not a helpful problem description. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen? Any errors? Also fix the title, it's pretty pointless.

Comment: What does `sscanf()` return?  And which one is line 137?  I doubt anyone is going to count that many lines of code.

Comment: I think you never initialize `data_struct->name`. Copying data into memory referenced by an uninitialized pointer, will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Mandatory read: [How To Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate a new structure `node_t`, its member `name` is an uninitialized pointer that cannot be initialized by `ini_struct()` with `strcpy(data_struct->name, "");` This has undefined behavior, and the same problem occurs in `insert_to_struct()`. A simple solution is to define `name` as an array of `char` like the members of `data`:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_STR];
    data_t data;
} athlete_t;
```

Note also that function `insert_to_struct` does not need line continuation characters `\`. It would be more readable as:

```
/* insert each value separated by comma into the struct we define */
void insert_to_struct(athlete_t *data_struct, char *new_line) {
    sscanf(new_line,
           "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],"
           "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],"
           "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]",
           data_struct->data.id, data_struct->name,
           data_struct->data.sex,
           data_struct->data.age, data_struct->data.height,
           data_struct->data.weight,data_struct->data.team,
           data_struct->data.noc, data_struct->data.games,
           data_struct->data.year, data_struct->data.season,
           data_struct->data.city, data_struct->data.sport,
           data_struct->data.event, data_struct->data.medal);
}
```

Note how a string constant can be broken in smaller chunks by just writing them one after the other without an operator. The compile will automatically glue these strings into a single literal.

Furthermore, it would be safer to specify the maximum number of characters to store into each of the destination arrays and verify that the 15 fields have been parsed correctly:

```
/* insert each value separated by comma into the struct we define */
int insert_to_struct(athlete_t *data_struct, char *new_line) {
    return sscanf(new_line,
                  "%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],"
                  "%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],"
                  "%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,],%127[^,]",
                  data_struct->data.id, data_struct->name,
                  data_struct->data.sex,
                  data_struct->data.age, data_struct->data.height,
                  data_struct->data.weight,data_struct->data.team,
                  data_struct->data.noc, data_struct->data.games,
                  data_struct->data.year, data_struct->data.season,
                  data_struct->data.city, data_struct->data.sport,
                  data_struct->data.event, data_struct->data.medal) == 15;
}
```

Note also that this rudimentary parser does not handle quotes strings, strings with embedded quotes and/or commas, nor does it accept empty fields. A hand coded parser would be needed to read the file properly.